# Security Certificate

Tags: linux, up2date

I have the "logwatch" service turned on and I expect to get a mail everyday.
Today's mail titled "Logwatch for servername (Linux)" has the following section...

```
 --------------------- up2date Begin ------------------------

 **Unmatched Entries**
 The certificate is expired. Please ensure you have the correct certificate and your system time is correct.
```

I checked and my system time is correct. What is this certificate that has been referred to?
I am using CentOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick [google search](http://www.google.ca/search?ie=UTF-8&q=up2date) turned up a [Wikipedia page for up2date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up2date).

Two things stand out:

> up2date is no longer shipped with the distribution; yum is used instead.

It sounds like up2date is very, very out of date. You may want to look at upgrading your OS or transitioning to `yum`.

Second,

> CentOS's up2date downloads packages from yum repositories on the CentOS Mirror Network

I'd have to guess one of the servers it tried to download an updated package list from had an expired SSL certificate.